# Selenium: Drag and Drop element with Java Robot or Action

Tags: java, selenium, action, awtrobot

As a part of my Selenium WebDriver test I need to Drag some `HTML` element, Move it to some location and Drop (release) it there.
I tried the following codes:

1) Using the `Action`

```
     Action rotateText = builder.clickAndHold(textRotator)  
             .moveByOffset(xRotatorOffset, yRotatorOffset)  
             .release(textRotator)  
             .build();  
     rotateText.perform();
```

`textRotator`is the element I'm trying to drag and move.
In the case of code as it appears here the element is moved to desired position but is instantly got back to the original position when `release` action applied.
If I omit the `.release(textRotator)`part  - the element is leaved on desired location but it is not released, each mouse movement affects the element location and brings it to absolutely unwanted location.

2) With `Robot`

```
robot.mouseMove(textRotatorPoint);  //The element I want to drag and move  
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);  
robot.mouseMove(xTextOffset,yTextOffset);  // the new location I want to move the element to  
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

In this case mouse is thrown to some strange location, near the upper-left corner of the web page, out of the frame I'm working with area.
The desired element is not moved to any place...
**Update:** In the meantime I found some workaround for the first code by adding the `.click()`. Now it looks

```
     Action rotateText = builder.clickAndHold(textRotator)  
             .moveByOffset(xRotatorOffset, yRotatorOffset)  
             .click()                
             .release(textRotator)  
             .build();  
     rotateText.perform();
```

And it works. 
So now my question is: is this the right and the only way to perform this action by `Action` and how to perform this using `robot`